Exporting a report with selected slicers with Power BI REST API (no javascript)
I am using the Power BI REST API to export a file in PDF/PPTX format using the ExportTo endpoint. Our reports contain a lot of slicers, and I need to export the file with certain slicers selected. From what I can infer from the documentation, I can pass a defaultBookmark in the powerBIReportConfiguration object in the request. The problem is that I am not rendering the report in Javascript, and the only way I know of to generate a bookmark is through the bookmarksManager.capture(options) call using the Javascript library. Is there a way to generate the bookmark through the REST API, or is there any other way to make the REST API apply slicer selections to the export?
